# I need help creating a button that will save the user current location and multiple others if they move so I can export those locations via a CSV file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, maps

So I am having some trouble to pass the longitude and latitude of the current location from my locationManager function to my button function. Id like the button to store the user coordinates in a variable then have that variable pass to my task class so I can export it via email as a .csv file. That file will then be uploaded to a map I am creating for work.
Here is my code:

```
//
// ViewController.swift
// project
//
// Created by Tyler Struntz on 6/22/18.
// Copyright © 2018 Tyler Struntz. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import MessageUI
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
@IBAction func saveLocation(_ sender: Any)
{
}
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
//creating CSV file
var taskArr = [Task]()
var task: Task!
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
let location = locations[0]
let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0001, 0.0001)
let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
let _:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
self.map.showsUserLocation = true
let latCord = location.coordinate.latitude
let lonCord = location.coordinate.longitude
// print("--------------------\n")
// print("\(location.coordinate.latitude)")
// print("--------------------\n")
}
override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
////////////////////////////////////////
task = Task()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
class Task: NSObject
{
var name: String = ""
var latitude = Float("")
var longitude = Float("")
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: So put this inside the body of locationManager (2nd part) @Nasir

Answer (score 0):

Why not define myLocation as an optional var such as

```
var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
```

And then inside **`didUpdateLocations`** function, you can initialize it like

```
myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
```

And inside the button click, you have this code:

```
if let location=myLocation {
   /* Code for saving the coordinates to CSV. Make sure to use location (or myLocation!) */
}
```